# Elasticsearch : Meaning of "@" symbol

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

So I haven't been able to find anything in the Elasticsearch documentation regarding the meaning of using a `@` prefix for field names (if there is a doc about this, my question might have an easy answer).

I've seen it used in cases where the field represents something *about* the log line - easy example being `@timestamp`, in the case of `AWS Cloudwatch` logs to `AWS Elasticsearch Service` it passes things like `@log_group`, `@id`, etc.

It would be interesting to know if using the `@` symbol is simply a naming convention (someone decided to distinguish log line meta information from pertinent fields), or if there is some kind of functional difference in prefixing the field name with `@`.

Any insight (or answers)?

Comment: It used to be important for logstash and elasticsearch in the very early versions. I still use it to maintain the fact that those fields need populating for time series and similar data. Not 100% required anymore though

Answer (score 8):

`@` doesn't have a special meaning inside Elasticsearch.

Logstash uses this convention to define some "metadata" fields for the events, like `@timestamp` and `@version`.

Answer (score 1):

Really i don't find any official documentation about this in Elasticsearch, but, i find that some libraries who uses Elasticsearch results points `@` as a annotation, to specify what's the _timestamp for example.

For example, as explain in this [issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1444), the Grafana uses the `@timestamp` annotation for default, and if you use a custom timestamp you will need to specify they.